# Correlated subquery & conditional where clause in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a correlated subquery that is validated based on the column value. Even though I read through the `sequelize` docs and examples on GitHub, I did not really get any working solutions.

Query I am trying to execute

```sql
select count(*) from table1 t1 
where case when deciding_col=1 then t1.id in 
(select distinct t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.id=t1.id and t2.second_condition=132) 
else 1=1 end;
```

Any references or suggestions are appreciated.

Update:

The goal is to fetch all records from `table1`, but if `deciding_col` value is true for a record, then I need to check if that particular record exist in table2.

Example: 
`Table1 Data:`

```
id | name | deciding_col
1    abcd    1
2    edfg    0
3    xyz     0
```

`Table2 Data:`

```
id | second_condition
1    132
```

Output:
**1.**

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 
where case when deciding_col=1 then t1.id in 
(select distinct t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.id=t1.id and t2.second_condition=132) 
else 1=1 end;
```

```
id | name | deciding_col
1    abcd    1
2    edfg    0
3    xyz     0
```

**2.**

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 
where case when deciding_col=1 then t1.id in 
(select distinct t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.id=t1.id and t2.second_condition=133) 
else 1=1 end;
```

```
id | name | deciding_col
2    edfg    0
3    xyz     0
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @P.Salmon update my question with the details

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to the question as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon added

Comment: Ok You have given actual output - what output did you want?

Comment: I need the same output but using `sequelize` npm package.